# Python update multiple cells using different cell references with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, automation

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference
import string

excelFile = pd.read_excel('file name')

wb = load_workbook('file name')
sheet = wb['sheet name']


sheet['T2'] = '=IF(J2 = "L", 1, 0)'
sheet['T3'] = '=IF(J3 = "L", 1, 0)'
sheet['T4'] = '=IF(J4 = "L", 1, 0)'
sheet['T5'] = '=IF(J5 = "L", 1, 0)'
sheet['T6'] = '=IF(J6 = "L", 1, 0)'
```

I have this code that updates the cell T2 using an IF formula. If J2 is "L", then T2 will be 1 otherwise it will be 0.

I want to follow this same formula for T3, T4, T5, etc... but referencing back to J3, J4, J5, to check if it is "L".

I've tried my hand at using some for loops but I cannot get anything to stick.

Attempt:

```
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    excel_alphabet = alphabet[0:max_col] # note that Python index begins at 0 (A = 0, B = 1, etc.)

    for letter in excel_alphabet:
        if letter != 'A':
            sheet['sheet name'] = '=IF(J2 = "Low", 1, 0)'
```

I want this to ultimately be automated so that I run the defined function and it loops through, updates the cells, and saves it.

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

f-strings (formatted strings) can be used to reference multiple variables in a single string. So, you can define a variable for the target row based on the desired start row and a variable for the column letter, and combine them with an f-string. the f-string format is to prefix the string with an 'f' and, inside the string, wrap the referenced variables in curly brackets {}.

Then use a for-loop to loop through the desired number of rows. The desired start row number should be constant added to 'x' in the for-loop.

Regarding my ascii import, doing it this way imports the list of uppercase letters as a list, so you can access the contents by index. I'm not sure if the 'as UPPER' is the norm, but I think it looks cleaner in the code.

Notes on your code:

- When you're slicing a list ([x:y]), if you're starting at 0, you don't need to include the 0. "[0:max_col]" is the same as "[:max_col]"

Happy coding!

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from string import ascii_uppercase as UPPER

test_xl = "test.xlsx"

# load workbook
wb = load_workbook(test_xl)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# loop through and edit rows
num_rows = 5
for x in range(num_rows):
    # define the target cell where the formula will be placed
    target_row = x + 2
    target_cell_letter = UPPER[19]
    target_cell = f"{target_cell_letter}{target_row}"

    # define the referenced cell (J)
    ref_cell_letter = UPPER[9]
    ref_cell = f"{ref_cell_letter}{target_row}"
    formula = f'=IF({ref_cell} = "L", 1, 0)'

    # write formula to cell
    ws[target_cell] = formula

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```